What are the most number of bits ever used in arbitrary/multiple precision floating point arithmetic?
I've been exploring the evolution of floating-point arithmetic formats from single to octuple precision. Here's what I THINK I have learned about the key specifications and capabilities for each precision level I've learned about:
Single Precision (32-bit):
Bits (Significand/Sign/Exponent): 24 (1 implicit + 23 explicit)/23/1/8
Decimal Precision: ~7-8 digits
Bias: 127
Range: 2^-126 to 2^127
Double Precision (64-bit):
Bits (Significand/Sign/Exponent): 53 (1 implicit + 52 explicit)/52/1/11
Decimal Precision: ~15-17 digits
Bias: 1023
Range: 2^-1022 to 2^1023
Quadruple Precision (128-bit):
Bits (Significand/Sign/Exponent): 113 (1 implicit + 112 explicit)/112/1/15
Decimal Precision: ~33-36 digits
Bias: 16383
Range: 2^-16382 to 2^16383
Octuple Precision (256-bit):
Bits (Significand/Sign/Exponent): 237 (1 implicit + 236 explicit)/236/1/19
Decimal Precision: ~69-72 digits
Bias: 262143
Range: 2^-262142 to 2^262143
Lastly, I learned about arbitrary precision floating point, where you can basically choose the precision you want. So, this led me to the obvious question of how precise have people gone?
Question:
Given these advancements, what is the highest precision floating-point arithmetic that has ever been utilized, in practical or theoretical applications? How many bits were used for the exponent, significand, and sign? (Is there ever any situation in which you would use more than one sign bit?) What specific application or use case required such high precision?

"Extended" and "arbitrary" precision are two different things.  True arbitrary-precision libraries are just that: arbitrary.  You can have the equivalent of thousands of bits of precision, virtually as many as you want.  The "size" (memory footprint) of an arbitrary-precision number typically varies, at runtime, as needed.  (A lot like variable-length strings.)  One popular arbitrary-precision library is GMP.

Also notable are the Unix/Linux arbitrary-precision calculators dc and bc.

@SteveSummit how did I not make that clear in the question? I said, " arbitrary precision floating point, where you can basically choose the precision you want." That was the ENTIRE point of the question, I want to know HOW arbitrary people have gone.

@SteveSummit those calculators are fascinating. It makes PERFECT sense to me that one of the first Unix programs was an arbitrary precision calculator, considering precise math is one of the ultimate quests of man. It makes me wonder how they achieve this with finite bits, maybe that's another question.

Sorry, perhaps I read your question too hastily.  The specific examples you cited (quadruple, octuple) are examples of what I believe are called extended precision (not "arbitrary"), which is why I felt the need to make that point.

Also, it's only the extended formats for which it seemed meaningful to ask or answer the question, "what is the highest that has ever been utilized?".  For arbitrary precision, it's like asking, "What's the longest null-terminated string that someone has ever used?"

It makes me wonder how they achieve this with finite bits Well, of course, "arbitrary" isn't "infinite".  The arbitrary-precision tools I'm familiar with are all limited by the amount of memory you have available.

In terms of allocating exponent versus significand bits, this answer over on retrocumputing.se has some interesting information.

One example: David H. Bailey and Jonathan M. Borwein, "Hand-to-hand combat with thousand-digit integrals." Journal of Computational Science, 3(3), 77-86.
"We find that ... such integrals can be 'experimentally' evaluated in closed form or that intriguing linear relations exist within a class of similar integrals. Discovering these identities and relations often requires the evaluation of integrals to extreme precision ... To better understand these integrals, we computed a large number of them ... to extreme precision: 1500-digit precision in most cases,
with some to 3000-digit precision."
